# Is GDDR related to DDR?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, ddr

I have a graphics card—[Nvidia ENGT240](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_gt_240_us.html)—that has DDR3. Now I'm not sure, but is DDR3 the same as GDDR3 when It's on a graphics card?

I know that DDR is for Computer Ram and GDDR  is for Graphics RAM, but for me it shows DDR for graphics card.

Comment: Are you 100% positive you have a graphics card with DDR3 because that doesn't sound right.  How did you determine it had DDR3 memory instead of GDDR3?  **There is a huge difference.**  Please update your question with specifics.

Comment: Yes I am 100% sure, got it even on the box, I'll send you a picture if you like :P weird for me to :P

Comment: Just tell me the model.  I can find it myself.

Comment: Nvidia ENGT240.

Comment: The box is in error.  The [card](http://www.asus.com/Graphics_Cards/ENGT240DI1GD3A/specifications/) in question has GDDR3 memory.  [This](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_gt_240_us.html) is the reference specifications for that card it either has GDDR5 or GDDR3 memory.

Comment: @Ramhound if you look at the specifics of the card (on the link indicated) I think he is misled under the memory clock section

Comment: @SimonSheehan - You are right which is the reason the specifications online are correct since it clearly indicates GDDR3 and GDDR5 memory being used.